# If a UA Artificer infuses a weapon and uses it as a spellcasting focus, can it be used for the somatic component of a spell too?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, spell-components, spellcasting-focus, artificer

The new [Artificer class (from Unearthed Arcana)](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/artificer-revisited) for 5e can infuse magic into weapons or shields, and use the infused item as a spell focus for material components. However, can you wave your focus for the somatic part of a spell as well?

Basically, I am curious whether an artificer can have a one-handed crossbow in one hand, and an infused shield in the other and still cast V, S, M spells.

Comment: Welcome to Rpg.SE! Your question is already answered elsewhere - but I'll add that holding a one-handed corssbow in one hand, and an infused shield il the other will allow you to cast spells, but not to shoot more than 1 bolt. You need a free hand to reload.